# I can't see Firebase analytics from my iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-analytics

My `Firebase Analytics` doesn't work. After reinstall my macOS I downloaded my source code of the iOS app from the Github then upload a new version of my app to the AppStore and suddenly my firebase analytics stopped working.

I tried to remove `GoogleService-Info.plist` then download a new one from the Firebase and put it into the project and release a new version of the app but still I can't see firebase analytics.

I use last versions of Xcode, Cocoapods, iOS, macOS

I have these pods in `Podfile`

```
pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
pod 'Firebase/Core'
```

Did anybody have a same problem? Thank you for your responses.

Comment: You probably need to update your cocoapods to 1.10.0 or later `sudo gem install cocoapods`, and ensure you're using XCode 12.2 or later, also your target must be iOS 10.0 or later. Also note *The Firebase iOS library Firebase/Core is no longer needed. This SDK included the Firebase SDK for Google Analytics.*

Comment: Thanks for response. I use the last version of Cocoapods,Xcode,iOS...

Comment: Please update the *question* with that information so future readers dont have to search through he comments for it. That will make crafting an answer easier.

Comment: Oh... I tried to downgrade Firebase Analytics and it works...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. I had to downgrade `Firebase/Analytics` to version `6.1.1` from version `7.7.0`.

Comment: A better solution is to add `-ObjC` to the `Other Linker Flags` Build Setting. Details at https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/7595#issuecomment-786087841

Comment: Yes the "-ObjC" flag is working ! thank @PaulBeusterien